# How to use XML without the libxml PHP extension

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml, libxml2

Is it possible to parse an XML file without the libxml extension (included with a PHP installation by default)? There is of course, a possibility to write a XML parser myself, but that will cost me lots of work. Is there any pure PHP XML parser available I can use, or is there any other method?
I'd like to implement this in my CMS, to support servers which don't have `libxml`, or any other library/extension installed. I can't use `simplexml` because this library is included with`libxml`.

Thanks in advance,
Tim Visée

Comment: According to [PHP doc](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php), `simplexml` is default enabled... Why you can't use it?

Comment: The problem is not that I'm not able to use it. I want to support servers which don't have `simplexml` enabled, server owners can disable this for various reasons. So my question is is there a different way to parse these XML files without `libxml`?

Comment: There're tons of ways: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

Comment: All of these methods described on the page you send, require `libxml`, there's one method that doesn't require this extension, but this will require a different extension instead which isn't installed by default. As I already said in my answer above, I would like to read XML without having the libxml or any other extensions installed, is this possible?